# How do I create custom control or action that works in a list's DataSheet view?

Tags: lookup-column, custom-field-types, datasheet

I have created a cascading lookup column field for a list in sharepoint 2010. It's working fine in the Standard view but not in the DataSheet view.

In datasheet view it is showing all the possible options in child column; it isn't applying the parent column's filter.

For example: If you select the country India in the parent column, it should only show Indian countries in the child column; but in the DataSheet view it's showing all the other options.

How can I change the behaviour of the child column to filter the available options??

Answer (score 3):

The DataSheet view is unfortunately not customisable; SharePoint uses Access to render the sheet, which uses its own controls and methods.

Comment: Hi stuart, thanks for ur reply. you mean, it is not at all possible to filter the content of child column of a list in a datasheet view? Then how to enable cascade lookup dropdowns for datasheet view? please give me solution for that

Comment: @Suresh: I'm afraid there is no solution that I'm aware of.

Answer (score -3):

You may also want to try KWizCom's list inline editor. This SharePoint add-on works in all browsers and also allows you to bulk-edit items that include custom columns:
http://www.kwizcom.com/sharepoint-add-ons/list-in-line-editor/overview/

Comment: We  require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.